# Can Struts 2 handle 3 action class calls at the same time

Tags: struts2

I am using ajax to load 3 jsps in a master page but the problem is it loads one after the other? I wanted to know if struts 2 can handle 3 action class calls at the same time? Or is it even possible to make such calls? My page is getting slow because of this, is there any other way to handle this?

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="col1">
        <div id="content_right">
            <div class="curved section_content">
                <div id="sub_header" class="curved_top">
                    <h2>
                        <s:text name="ft.history.title.details" />
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <sj:div cssClass="ajaxDiv" href="transferdetailhistory"
                    id="transfer_detail_content">
                    <div class="ajaxSection">
                        <div class="centeredAjaxSection">
                            <center>
                                <img style="vertical-align: middle;" alt="Loading"
                                    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/bigindicator.gif">
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        </d‌​iv>
                </sj:div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this would load the history page, like wise i load 2 more jsps

Comment: Instead of asking for code, you may want to put in **your** code snippets in your question to help clarify your question so that others can help you better.

Comment: I suspect a client side issue, check what is happening with firebug to make sure the Ajax requests really are happening asynchronously and something silly like waiting for a response before issuing the next call isn't happening.

Answer (score 2):

Struts2 can handle significantly more than three simultaneous requests. There are many large, scalable applications using the Struts2 framework.

The issue is most likely related to your code.

Comment: Is it possible to get a sample code or a link.. kind of urgent.

Answer (score 0):

we are in our application using such cases in every now and than and never faced problem with this.
better come up with some code may be problem with your code or some configuration as Steven said in his repply

Comment: <div id="content"><div class="col1"><div id="content_right">
<div class="curved section_content"><div id="sub_header" class="curved_top"><h2><s:text name="ft.history.title.details" /></h2></div><sj:div cssClass="ajaxDiv"  href="transferdetailhistory" id="transfer_detail_content"><div class="ajaxSection"><div class="centeredAjaxSection"><center><img style="vertical-align:middle;" alt="Loading" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/bigindicator.gif"></center></div></div></sj:div></div></div></div> this would load the history page, like wise i load 2 more jsps..

Comment: Got the issue fixed.. had some issues in the back end.. thanks to everyone